Python PyQt5 multiprocessing vs asyncio (custom solution)
pyqt5: main_ui.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 32)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_1.setText("")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 with Processes or asyncio")

Solution1 QThread/Process: main.py
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys, os

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QThread, QTimer
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pipe

import random

import threading
import time

class Main:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.show()
        
        self.create_process()
        
        '''
        self.put_data_timer = QTimer()
        self.put_data_timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.put_data())
        self.put_data_timer.setSingleShot(False)
        self.put_data_timer.start(1000)
        '''
        
        self.run_thread = True
        self.put_data_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.put_data_thread_method)
        self.put_data_thread.start()
        
        self.MainWindow.closeEvent = lambda event: self.closeEvent(event)
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def put_data(self):
        random_int = random.randint(0, 10000)
        self.queue.put({'type':'input_data','input_data':random_int})
        
    def put_data_thread_method(self):
        while(self.run_thread):
            random_int = random.randint(0, 10000)
            self.queue.put({'type':'input_data','input_data':random_int})
            time.sleep(0.020)
        
    def create_process(self):
        self.mother_pipe, self.child_pipe = Pipe()
        self.queue = Queue()

        self.emitter = Emitter(self.mother_pipe)
        self.emitter.error_signal.connect(lambda error_message: print(error_message))
        self.emitter.one_signal.connect(lambda data: self.ui.label_1.setText(data))
        self.emitter.start()

        self.child_process = Child_Proc(self.child_pipe, self.queue)
        self.child_process.start()
        
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.run_thread = False
        self.put_data_thread.join()
        #self.put_data_timer.stop()
        self.queue.put({'type':'close'})
        self.child_process.join()
        self.child_process.terminate()
        self.emitter.quit()
        event.accept()
        


class Emitter(QThread):
    error_signal = pyqtSignal(str)
    one_signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, from_process: Pipe):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_from_process = from_process

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.data_from_process.recv()
                if data["type"] == "error":
                    self.error_signal.emit(data["error_message"])
                elif data["type"] == "data":
                    self.one_signal.emit(data["data"])
                elif data["type"] == "close":
                    return None
            except:
                error_message = traceback.format_exc()
                self.error_signal.emit(error_message)
                return None


class Child_Proc(Process):

    def __init__(self, to_emitter, from_mother):
        try:
            super().__init__()
            self.daemon = False
            self.to_emitter = to_emitter
            self.data_from_mother = from_mother
        except:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            to_emitter.put({"type": "error", "error_message": error_message})
            os._exit(1)

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            data = self.data_from_mother.get()
            if data['type'] == 'close':
                self.to_emitter.send(data)
                return None
            elif data['type'] == 'input_data':
                input_data = data['input_data']
                input_data *= 10
                self.to_emitter.send({'type':'data','data':str(input_data)})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    program = Main()

Solution2 asyncio (custom): main_asyncio.py
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
import sys
import random
import time
import asyncio
import qasync
from aioprocessing import AioProcess, AioQueue

import threading
import time

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.loop = qasync.QEventLoop(self.app)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        self.MainWindow.show()

        # Setup inter-process communication
        self.input_queue = AioQueue()
        self.output_queue = AioQueue()
        self.process = AioProcess(target=process_run, args=(self.input_queue, self.output_queue))
        self.process.start()

        self.run_thread = True
        self.put_data_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.put_data_thread_method)
        self.put_data_thread.start()

        asyncio.ensure_future(self.listen_to_output_queue())
        self.MainWindow.closeEvent = self.closeEvent

        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    async def listen_to_output_queue(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = await self.output_queue.coro_get()
                if data["type"] == "error":
                    print(f"Error: {data['message']}")
                elif data["type"] == "data":
                    self.ui.label_1.setText(data["message"])
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                break

    def put_data_thread_method(self):
        while self.run_thread:
            random_int = random.randint(0, 10000)
            self.input_queue.put({"type": "input_data", "input_data": random_int})
            time.sleep(0.020)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.run_thread = False
        self.put_data_thread.join()
        self.input_queue.put({"type": "close"})
        self.process.join()
        event.accept()


def process_run(input_queue, output_queue):
    while True:
        data = input_queue.get()
        if data["type"] == "close":
            break
        elif data["type"] == "input_data":
            result = data["input_data"] * 10
            output_queue.put({"type": "data", "message": str(result)})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()

Both solutions works, but for solution2 i have not full tested.
Furthermore i don't know how to improve solution2 using asyncio/pyqt5 asyncio functionallities.
I want to see the time of each implementation, to accept the faster and ignore the slower.
Also note that for the two solutions because the pairs or QThread/Process are many there is a sync thread like this:
import threading
import traceback
from multiprocessing import Condition, Value, Event
import time

class Sync_processes:
    def __init__(self, main_self):
        self.main_self = main_self

        self.condition = Condition()

        self.start_condition = Condition()
        self.continue_condition = Condition()

        self.frame = Value('q',100, lock=False)  # Shared frame counter

        # Shared boolean variable, initialized to False
        self.start_flag = Value('b', False, lock=False)
        self.continue_flag = Value('b', False, lock=False)
        self.quit_event = Event()
        self.pre_quit_event = Event()


        self.deck_1_flag = Value('b', False, lock=False)
        self.deck_2_flag = Value('b', False, lock=False)
        self.music_clip_deck_flag = Value('b', False, lock=False)
        self.final_slice_flag = Value('b', False, lock=False)
        self.final_slice_plot_flag = Value('b', False, lock=False)

        self.flag_condition = Condition()

    def start(self):
        with self.start_condition:
            self.start_flag.value = True
            self.start_condition.notify_all()
        if 'tr' not in dir(self):
            self.tr = threading.Thread(target=self.infinite_heartbeat, args=(self.main_self.configuration,))
            self.tr.start()

    def infinite_heartbeat(self, configuration):
        try:
            sync_cycle_ms = configuration.get("sync_cycle_ms", 100)
            if not isinstance(sync_cycle_ms, (int, float)) or sync_cycle_ms <= 0:
                raise ValueError("sync_cycle_ms must be a positive number.")
            sync_cycle_seconds = sync_cycle_ms / 1000

            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            next_expected_beat = start_time
            while not self.quit_event.is_set():
                next_expected_beat += sync_cycle_seconds

                time_to_sleep = next_expected_beat - time.perf_counter()
                if time_to_sleep > 0:
                    if not self.pre_quit_event.is_set():
                        time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
                else:
                    time_to_sleep = sync_cycle_seconds / 5
                    if not self.pre_quit_event.is_set():
                        time.sleep(time_to_sleep)

                with self.condition:
                    self.continue_flag.value = False
                    if not self.pre_quit_event.is_set():
                        self.frame.value += 1
                    else:
                        self.frame.value += 1000
                    self.condition.notify_all()
                    if self.quit_event.is_set():
                        return

                if not self.pre_quit_event.is_set():
                    with self.flag_condition:
                        self.flag_condition.wait_for(lambda: (self.quit_event.is_set() or (self.deck_1_flag.value and self.deck_2_flag.value and self.music_clip_deck_flag.value and self.final_slice_flag.value)))
                        if self.quit_event.is_set():
                            return

                time.sleep(sync_cycle_seconds/300)
                with self.continue_condition:
                    self.continue_flag.value = True
                    self.continue_condition.notify_all()
                    if self.quit_event.is_set():
                        return
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())

    def close(self):
        self.quit_event.set()
        self.tr.join()


and for the first solution this becomes like this:
    def run(self):
        try:
            self.fetch_player_list_settings()

            with self.start_condition:
                self.frame_number.value += 1
                self.current_frame = self.frame_number.value
                self.start_condition.wait_for(lambda: self.start_flag.value)

            while (not self.quit_event.is_set()) and (not self.pre_quit_event.is_set()):

                with self.condition:
                    self.condition.wait_for(lambda: self.current_frame < self.frame_number.value or self.pre_quit_event.is_set())
                    if self.pre_quit_event.is_set():
                        break

                with self.deck_1_condition:
                    self.deck_1_flag.value = True
                    self.deck_1_condition.notify_all()

                with self.continue_condition:
                    self.continue_condition.wait_for(lambda: self.continue_flag.value or self.pre_quit_event.is_set())
                    if self.pre_quit_event.is_set():
                        break

                    result = self.one_chunk()  # Process one chunk of data
                    if result == "close":
                        break

                    self.current_frame += 1

                    with self.deck_1_condition:
                        self.deck_1_flag.value = False
                        self.deck_1_condition.notify_all()

            while (self.data_from_mother.qsize() > 0):
                _ = self.data_from_mother.get()
            self.data_from_mother.put({"type": "new-status", "status": 'stopped'})
            self.data_from_mother.put({"type": "close"})
            r = self.one_chunk()
            self.to_emitter.send({'type': 'close'})
            return
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            self.to_emitter.send({"type": "error", "error_message": error_message})


you won't find any performance difference in practice, just pick whatever is easier to use and more convenient, both of them work fundamentally the same, a thread grabs messages and sends it back to the main thread, the second one just hides it inside of asyncio so you look like you are using only 1 thread when you are not, in fact both of them use 4 threads, one for each queue, and one for waiting on the queue and last one for the GUI.

These sorts of tests are rather pointless because the background tasks aren't doing any meaningful work. It's the nature of the work that most often dictates the correct choice of solution, not mere performance.
